# Not able to publish a message to ActiveMQ using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jms, activemq-classic, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I would like publish some messages and perform load testing of my docker-based `ActiveMQ` server using `JMeter`. I have the configuration in place but for some reason I am not able to see the message getting published in `ActiveMQ`.

I have the admin console up and running and see that the queues is not getting created either. I also tried to manually create the queue and see if the Jmeter script works, but no luck

I have already added `activemq-all-5.15.0` jar in my `jmeter/lib/ext` folder of JMeter 3.2.

I am also seeing following error in JMeter Results Tree.

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jmeter-q
    at org.apache.activemq.jndi.ReadOnlyContext.lookup(ReadOnlyContext.java:235)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.Utils.lookupDestination(Utils.java:148)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.Publisher.<init>(Publisher.java:134)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.PublisherSampler.initClient(PublisherSampler.java:181)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.PublisherSampler.sample(PublisherSampler.java:206)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.BaseJMSSampler.sample(BaseJMSSampler.java:98)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:491)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:425)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The correct format to provide destination under Destination textbox is

```
dynamicQueues/jmeter-q
```

Also please make sure that there should be no spaces at the end of each fields like provideURl, connectionf factory etc.

Comment: Is it mandatory to specify "dynamicQueues" or it could be any other string ?

Comment: yes its mandatory for Queue and for topic it would be dynamicTopics.